# Inner Join between three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following query:

```
select a.idclientecrm, max(c.falta) from clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm a
inner join clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm b on (a.idclientecrm=b.idclientecrm and   a.idlistadeclientescrm = 58)
inner join tareas c on a.idclientecrm=c.idclientecrm
where b.idlistadeclientescrm = 70
```

But I'm not getting the result I want. I know I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

I want the outcome of the first inner join (aprox 22k rows) but I need to join the result to the "tareas" table and get the max date from there.

I want to use **max** because for every **idclientecrm**, there's more than one row that matches in the "tareas" table and I need the last recorded result.

If I left out something let me know.

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Do you want the max from the tareas table whether or not it has a match in clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm?

Comment: You are asking to know if I should use a left join instead of a inner join? I think either way is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to move the "58" condition to the WHERE clause and group on a.idclientecrm:

```
select a.idclientecrm, max(c.falta) 
from clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm a
inner join clientescrmporlistadeclientescrm b 
on a.idclientecrm = b.idclientecrm
inner join tareas c 
on a.idclientecrm = c.idclientecrm
where b.idlistadeclientescrm = 70
and a.idlistadeclientescrm = 58
group by a.idclientecrm
```

Comment: the group by was one of the reasons. Thnx